# How to iterate through $.JSON results array with $.each

Tags: json, each

I am only getting back the first result in the array, and want to retrieve all the available results.

```
    function runForm(){
        $("#stock_news").html("");
        var stockSymbol = $("input").val();

//very long str

 var newsStocks = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?
    q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com
%2Fq%3Fs%3D"+stockSymbol+"'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22yfi_headlines
     %22%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Ful%2Fli%2Fa'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";

//getJSON       

$.getJSON(newsStocks, function(data) {
  var headlines = data.query.results.a[0];
//newsStr

  newsStr = "<h3 style='text-decoration:underline'>Current Headlines</h3><p><ol>
<li><a href='"+headlines.href+"'>"+headlines.content+
    "</a></li></ol></p>";
    $("#stock_news").html(newsStr);
                });
```

Comment: I believe my answer if very sufficient. If you agree, please click the accept arrow on it. You may not know about that yet - being a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given enough information, but I could guess that this `var headlines = data.query.results.a[0];` is your issue. It would seem like the other results are there, but you're filtering them out. `console.log(data)` and `console.log(data.query.results)` and look at what all is in there. Otherwise, update your question with more information.

**Update:**

This is a very basic ajax call (with jQuery) and a `for loop` to loop through and use each result.

```
$.get('path/here', function(data) {
  //if your data is an array
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    var item = data[i];
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

[Here's a live demo (click)](http://jsbin.com/eSiLiCe/1/edit), but I'm not going to use the ajax data since the path is not valid.

Here's the same example, but using `$.each`. I prefer the `for loop`...why use jQuery for something so simple?

```
$.get('path/here', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(item, index) {
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

Comment: you are correct, the `var headlines` is my issue. It is only returning the first result from `var newsStocks`....that's why I don't know how to iterate through those results.

Comment: @user2997527 then stop filtering them out? `data` contains the full results from the server. Everything afterwards is just selecting less and less information. For example, `data.query.results.a[1]` should be the next result from set `a`, whatever that is. Did you not do as I said and `console.log(data)`? You would be able to look in the console and click through the whole object of `data`.

Comment: I tried printing these both, and I'm not getting any results to print out.  In the case of `console.log(data.query.results)` it prints undefined.  I want to be able to loop through `data.query.results`...a[0] through however many there are and print them all, but I am not sure how that is done via a `$.each` possibly in JSON, but I am not familiar with the language's syntax.

Comment: If that is undefined, then the results you're looking for don't exist. It isn't reasonable to expect someone on SO to do all of your work for you because you don't know how. As I said, log just data to see what you are getting from the server and work it out from there. All you need is a simple for loop to use each piece of data.

Comment: but when I print a[0], it is returning me a result, therefore something is right there.

Comment: You're so lost, there's no way to help you. If "results" is undefined, then its property "a" is undefined. Learn JavaScript. This is extremely basic.

Comment: When I do `var headlines = data.query.results.a[0]`; or `var headlines = data.query.results.a[1]`  etc., I am getting results back that I want. I don't know what the console is supposed to print...I am using http://jsfiddle.net/xu2FJ/52/ I know that I somehow have to loop the array to get them all to show. I just don't know how. If you can direct me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. I might be asking stupid questions, b/c, as I said, I don't know/understand this language well enough.

Comment: @user2997527 see my updated answer. This is more than enough to help you solve your issue.